# Eclipse plugin doesnot run multiple times in the new workspace

Tags: eclipse, swt, eclipse-plugin

We have developed eclipse plugin which will convert the jsp to wicket framework.

Our tool will parse the jsp files and convert them to wicket using antlr.

-

- we will run our plugin project using eclipse application.
- A new runtime eclipse application will open with the plugin symbol in the tool bar.
- For the first time when we click on the plugin symbol, the wizard pages are getting opened and the tool is parsing  the jsp files and convert them to wicket using antlr.
- After parsing the jsp files our tool  generates some validator classes using velocity templates, and generates some other classes using templates that are necessary for the generated wicket project to run on the server.
- Next time in the same runtime apllication if we click on the plugin symbol the wizard pages are getting opened but the parsing of jsp files is not performed.

what might be the issue? please help us.
Sorry we couldnot provide the code.

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if it contains any messages related to your code.